# How to get the latest photo album id of user ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how to use Facebook Graph API to get last photo album id of user?

Comment: More question marks does not net you more answers.

Comment: facebook returns album ids in the order of usage with the most recent being first in the returned list.

Comment: Hello Jayrox,,, what you say is false. Check out this:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.getAlbums
Log in to your Facebook account and try the example at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the album FQL table

`SELECT object_id, created FROM album WHERE owner = me() ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`